# Unity translate point relative to another point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, point

I have two points--let's say, A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2). What I do need is to move both of those points into direction of the Vector AB while pressing the Horizontal axis. How can I achieve that using the Translate method? Like I need to write something like this:

```
A.translate(pointingVector, Space.World)
```

The point B moves automatically fitting the transform of the point A, so no need to move it as moving the A point would also move the AB vector without changing its length and direction.

Comment: You mean you want to move both of these points the same distance in the direction of the AB vector or each one a different distance?

Comment: Do you want to make A follow to B?

Comment: @D.Christodoulou, yes, I want to move both two points the same distance in the direction of AB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, then this is simply a matter of moving the 2 points along the Vector that they create. So first you need to create the directional Vector:

```
// Gets a vector that points from the first point's position to the second's.
var (or Vector3) direction = p1.position - p2.position;
```

Then just increase the 2 points' position by that vector whenever you press the horizontal axis:

```
p1.position += direction * Time.deltaTime
```

Comment: Thanks, I already found the solution, but it was helpful, too